# Django extends existing apps

Tags: python, django

I installed app https://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks, next I want to extend this app model https://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks/blob/master/flatblocks/models.py. New models.py looks

```
class MyFlatBlock(FlatBlock):

    my_field = models.CharField()
```

How can I do this, whitout coping all app (django-flatblocks) to my project and rewrite this model?

Answer (score 0):

Create another model

```
class MyFlatBlock(models.Model):
    flat_block = models.OneToOneField(FlatBlock, related_name='extra')
    my_field = models.CharField()
```

Then you will be able to use `flatblock.extra.my_field` (catching `AttributeError` if necessary).

Comment: Ok, in this example it will work!

What can I do, if I want to rewrite only this https://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks/blob/master/flatblocks/models.py 

Get for example something like this in the end of flatblocks/models.py: http://www.pastie.org/2036952

Comment: @Valentino Langarosa What do you want to achieve?